# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) while adding libsqlite3.tbd

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sqlite

I want to add database and tables in my application, but the issue is that when i try create database and tables i am getting following error, what could be the issue, please help,

i have used same code and everything on other project in that its working fine but doesn't works in this one

I have also added libsqlite3.tbd in build phase, link binary with items
below is the error i am facing.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/nareshyeligatty/Desktop/iPhoneProjects/NikitaWedsAnuj/libsqlite3.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/nareshyeligatty/Desktop/iPhoneProjects/NikitaWedsAnuj/libsqlite3.tbd (3 slices)
```

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate recordExistOrNotuser:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate recordExistOrNotuser:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate recordExistOrNotuser:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate recordExistOrNotuser:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate recordExistOrNotuser:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate recordExistOrNotuser:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate recordExistOrNotuser:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)